std::span as type erasure over contiguous block of memory
Can we tell this is an example of type erasure std::span provides over contiguous block of memory? I hardly see this feature of std::span discussed and wondering why?
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
void print (std::span<T> sp)
{
    for (const auto& item : sp)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
int main()
{

    std::vector<int> v{1,3,5};
    std::span<int> s1{v};

    print(s1);

    int cArr[]{1,2,4,8};
    std::span<int> s2{cArr};
    print(s2);

    std::string message ("Hello");
    std::span<char> s3{message};
    print(s3);

    std::array<int,6> arr {9,8,7,6,5,4};
    std::span<int> s4{arr};
    print(s4);
}


this is just  what span is made for. Its an abstraction from the actual storage. All you know is that there are some contiguous elements. What specifially do you miss being discussed?

for example from cppreference: "The class template span describes an object that can refer to a contiguous sequence of objects with the first element of the sequence at position zero." does not mention the type of the container. If you want to call it like that, this information has been erased

I'm not seeing "type erasure" here, at least not in a form that people would use that term for. This is just using templates; the template is a prototype that can be used with a family of types. That's what templates are for. "Type erasure" is generally something else.

@NicolBolas so the fact that spans perform element access with raw pointers to the memory doesn't mean that a span type erase
the information of where the elements are stored?

@Sami: What makes you say that it uses "raw pointers"? The span iterator doesn't have to be a raw pointer (though, since it is a contiguous container, its iterators must be convertible to raw pointers). Also, vector iterators could be raw pointers. So this isn't special.

Mostly depend of your definition of type-erasure.

@Jarod42 Type erasure, in general, is a programming technique by which the explicit type information is
removed from the program. It is a type of abstraction that ensures that the program does not explicitly
depend on some of the data types.

Do you consider std::string as type erasure, as it can be constructed from const char* or const char[N] or std::initializer_list<char> or even sub-string?

@NicolBolas it is internally uses raw pointer and a size (for dynamic extent); Isn't it?

2 raw pointers is also a possible implementation.

There is no type erasure here just a class template called std::span

Templates are a way to create prototypes for functions, classes or variables that allow them to interact with a family of types (or values) that is provided at compile time, but is not specifically known at the place where the function/class/variable is written. That's all your code is doing: using templates. print is a function template, and it works like any other function template
You could consider this to be a form of "type erasure" if you take that as its literal meaning. But that could be applied to any use of templates. Or uses of runtime polymorphism.
The term "type erasure" in a C++ context typically means something much more specific.
Let's say you have 3 pieces of code: A, B, and C. There is some object of type X, with that type being known by A. C also knows about type X. B is some kind of generic transport mechanism, a piece of glue that can connect various pieces of code.
The goal of type erasure is to allow B to work as glue between some hypothetical A and C to transport objects of type X, but without B itself knowing about X.
And without B itself being a template. Templates can be used to make type erasure happen, but a key point of type erasure as a distinct concept is that the transport mechanism itself is not a template.
std::any is one mechanism for using type erasure. It imposes some restrictions on what Xes it can store (they must be copyable). But std::function is also a type erasure mechanism. It is templated on a specific function prototype, but any (copyable) callable that can be invoked with that prototype can be shoved into a std::function.
I would not consider span to be doing "type erasure" in the same way as any or function. The type of the array is clearly spelled out, and while it could point to any array, the type of that array is not in any way hidden by span itself.
You can write a template function that takes an array of any type via a span, but that's just doing what templates do.

Thank you so much for the detailed explanations. If I remove the template part in the code example and have the function accept only std::span (only passing int, not string), would that be an example of type erasure? Would it fall into that category? Otherwise we need to have overloads and know underlying container implementation

@Sami you seem to not understand how templates work. std::span does not involve or require any type-erasure. std::span  "...A typical implementation holds a pointer to T, if the extent is dynamic, the implementation also holds a size...."

@RichardCritten maybe because I don't have 20-30 yeas of experiences in C++ like you guys!!! I am trying to learn!

@Sami: "would that be an example of type erasure?" No. There would be no type being erased. The function would be completely aware of the type of objects it is manipulating.

I would definitely consider this a form of type erasure in the exact same way as function_ref. The only real difference between span<int> (a non-owning contiguous range of int) and function_ref<void()> (a non-owning nullary callable) in this sense is that span<int> can do its thing without any overhead at all and without needing to refer to the original object, while function_ref in general cannot. But they serve the same purpose. Doesn't matter what the source container is, just use span to reduce the API surface.

"The function would be completely aware of the type of objects it is manipulatin" indeed if the type is span<char>, ie elements are int. The point OP is trying to get across is that you can get a span<char> from a std::string or a char[N], or other containers. The type of the container is erased. This is how I read the question at least. (Though I wonder why then they made print a template and add span<int> to the mix)
